# Must React components act like pure functions with respect to their props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm going through the React documentation and read this line (bolding theirs):

> **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**

Is this a strict requirement or a design principle to avoid unintended behavior?

The example Facebook provides of an "impure" function is one that modifies its input. But it looks like it is possible for a React component to modify the props it receives as input (I've mirrored the example below off of their own example).

[Code Pen: Impure Component w/ Respect to Props?](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNxZGW?editors=1011)

JSX code:

```
var Withdraw = React.createClass({
  render() {
    this.props.account.balance -= this.props.amount;
    return (
      <div>Balance: ${this.props.account.balance} </div>
    )
  }
})

var CounterContainer = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var account = { balance: 10 }
    return (
      <div>
        <Withdraw account={account} amount={2} />
        <Withdraw account={account} amount={2} />
      </div>
    )   
  }
})

React.render(<CounterContainer />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Also: I'm aware that the above *could* be written as a stateless functional component and that state should not be stored outside of `this.state`.

Answer (score 6):

Like facebook said, if you need it to change. Use state.

Functions have to be pure, meaning

1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices.
2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices.

in other words a pure function

- Given the same input, will always return the same output.
- Produces no  side effects
  . Relies on no external state.

> React is pretty flexible but it has a single strict rule:
>
> All React components must act like pure functions with respect to
>   their props.
>
> Of course, application UIs are dynamic and change over time. In the
>   next section, we will introduce a new concept of "state". State allows
>   React components to change their output over time in response to user
>   actions, network responses, and anything else, without violating this
>   rule.

Your [Facebook Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

Here is a nice [article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976#.fv7sbeudz)

More about [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Answer (score 2):

The Withdraw component can be made pure as below

```
const Withdraw = ({account, amount}) =>  
   <div>Balance: {account.balance - amount} </div>;
```

Simple right? This is what the pure component do

- Around 20% code can be reduced
- Can avoid the use this key word
- Useful for presentational components focus on the UI
- Improved performance since there’s no state or lifecycle methods
- Easy to Understand
- Easy to Test

Since stateless functional components don’t support local state you’re forced to put state management where it belongs in higher level container components or via Flux/Redux.

This is how the stateless functional components programatically enforce keeping the component pure